# How do I find the right way to locate the needed element using Selenium in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

Target:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.exportData('csv')"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> csv</a></li>
```

which is in

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.exportData('excel')"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> excel</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.exportData('pdf')"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> pdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.exportData('csv')"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> csv</a></li>
</ul>
```

In console, JS code works smoothly:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[2].click();
```

The code I wrote:

```
LINK = "http://e-licitatie.ro/pub/notices/contract-award-notices/list/3/1"
PATH = "/Users/ultiplex/Documents/WORKSPACE/insightout/chromedriver"
DRIVER = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
DELAY = 30

def wait(delay: int, xpath: str) -> None: 
    try:
        WebDriverWait(DRIVER, delay).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='block-ui-overlay']")))
        print('Overlay bypassed')
        WebDriverWait(DRIVER, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        print(f"Element {xpath} found")
    except: 
        print("Error")

def load_link(link: str) -> None: 
    DRIVER.get(LINK)
    print("Link loaded")    

def click(xpath: str, delay: int) -> None: 
    wait(delay, xpath)
    DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    print("Clicked")

def filter(fr_date: str, to_date: str) -> None: 
    DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='De la data']").send_keys(fr_date)
    DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Pana la data']").send_keys(to_date)
    print("Filter selected")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_link(LINK)
    click("//button[@class='pull-right btn btn-default']", DELAY)
    filter("31/03/2020", "01/04/2020")
    click("//button[@class='pull-right margin-left-5 btn btn-entity']", DELAY)
```

Clicking works in the above-mentioned example but I can't find a way to make it work for the last step - export.

Please support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first click on the export link to visible the list element then you can able to click on csv link. Add two lines after you click on search.

```
#Click on Export link
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='darkorange dropdown-toggle' and contains(.,'Export')]"))).click()
#Click on csv link
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//li//a[contains(.,'csv')]"))).click()
```

Full code block.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://e-licitatie.ro/pub/notices/contract-award-notices/list/3/1")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='pull-right btn btn-default']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='De la data']"))).send_keys("31/03/2020")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Pana la data']"))).send_keys("01/04/2020")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='pull-right margin-left-5 btn btn-entity']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='darkorange dropdown-toggle' and contains(.,'Export')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//li//a[contains(.,'csv')]"))).click()
```

Comment: ofc I had to click on export before clicking on file (braindead). there is nothing more deceptive than an obvious fact. thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath.

```
(//ul[@class='dropdown-menu'][2]//a)[3]
```

[image]

Or

```
//ul[@class='dropdown-menu'][2]//a[normalize-space(.)='csv']
```

[image]

Comment: first: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//ul[@class='dropdown-menu'][2]//a)[3]"}

Comment: second: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='dropdown-menu'][2]//a[normalize-space(.)='csv']"}

Comment: I know there are 3 'dropdown-menu' on the page. Does this make a difference to your suggestion?

Comment: You have to target the second dropdown-menu. This should work (for PDF export) : `(//ul[@class="dropdown-menu"])[2]/li[2]/a` Shortest form : `(//a[contains(@ng-click,'pdf')])[1]` Replace 'li[2]' with 'li[3]' in the first XPath and 'pdf' with 'csv' if you want CSV instead of PDF export.